# iphone-Mapkit : alert if a user is entering within a specific region

Tags: iphone, ios, location, mapkit

I want to locate if I/friend have entered in a certain region on map using mapkit. this region could be a town or city or a place of any radius. i have not found any help regarding, any help or even a way towards the goal would be highly appreciated.

PEACE

Answer (score 2):

There is a method on CLLocationManager which will let you do this: `startMonitoringForRegion:`, you pass a `CLRegion` which is basically just a point and a radius and it will call `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods when the user enters or exits this region

Answer (score 0):

Its just an idea. Refresh the app constantly at a distance and pass the current lat/long value to the server using webservice. And if current lat/long value is same as some specific lat/long then show UIAlertView. Hope that helps.